# Modify XPath to return second of two values

Tags: xpath

I have an XPath that returns two items. I want to modify it so that it returns only the second, or the last if there are more than 2.

```
//a[@rel='next']
```

I tried

```
//a[@rel='next'][2]
```

but that doesn't return anything at all. How can I rewrite the xpath so I get only the 2nd link?

Comment: The answer depends on what the first bracketed expression returned.  Some more context (i.e. the input XML) would be helpful.

Comment: I changed my mind for exactly that reason, rewrote my comment, but SO won't let me undo the markdown.

Comment: Yeah, one of the annoying things I don't like about SO.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in 
[XPATH : finding an attribute node (and only one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102317/xpath-finding-an-attribute-node-and-only-one)

In my case the right XPath would be

```
(//a[@rel='next'])[last()]
```

---

EDIT (by Tomalak) - Explanation:

This selects all `a[@rel='next']` nodes, and takes the last of the entire set:

```
(//a[@rel='next'])[last()]
```

This selects all `a[@rel='next']` nodes that are the respective last `a[@rel='next']` of the parent context each of them is in:

```
//a[@rel='next'][last()]   equivalent:   //a[@rel='next' and position()=last()]
```

This selects all `a[@rel='next']` nodes that are the second `a[@rel='next']` of the parent context each of them is in (in your case, each parent context had only one `a[@rel='next']`, that's why you did not get anything back):

```
//a[@rel='next'][2]        equivalent:   //a[@rel='next' and position()=2]
```

For the sake of completeness: This selects all `a` nodes that are the last of the parent context each of them is in, and of them only those that have `@rel='next'` (XPath predicates are applied from left to right!):

```
//a[last()][@rel='next']   NOT equiv!:   //a[position()=last() and @rel='next']
```