# How to select the first attribute node with a specific name with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to select the first attribute in my XML document that has the name `"valgfase"`

I have tried the following expressions:

```
string strExpression = "//@valgfase[1]";
```

and

```
string = //@valgfase[position() = 1]
```

When i execute my expression, it returns ALL elements that have the attribute "valgfase".

What is the right way to do this?

I am using `C#` with `XPathDocument` and `XPathNavigator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `(//@valgfase)[1]`.

You can see the explanation in the answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102317/xpath-finding-an-attribute-node-and-only-one).

Comment: I just want the attribute and it's value. Thanks. I edited the question, but will still accept your answer!